# division of binary numbers by 2 and 8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to chceck if some binary numbers are divisible by 2 or 8 and tell how many there is. I now that binary number is divisible by 2 when the last digit is 0 and by 8 when last 3 are 0, so this is my mode of action

```
twos = 0
eights = 0
file = 'numbers.txt'
with open(file) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line[-2:] == '0':
           twos += 1
        elif line[-3:] == '000':
           eights +=1
        print(twos) 
        print(eights)
```

tbh i don't now why this isn't working, my bet it's because of different data types but im new to python and can't figure where the error is

sample for numbers.txt

http://collabedit.com/5u4xa

Comment: What are the contents of `file = 'numbers.txt'`? You probable need to do a `line = line.strip()` inside your `for` loop because their is probably a `\n` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The last "digit" is `line[-1]` (or `line[-1:]`), not `line[-2:]` (according to the same logic by which `line[-3:]` is the last 3 "digits", not the last 2).
- Your code does not attempt to deal with newline characters at all.
- Your algorithm will miss numbers that are divisible by both 2 and 8 because of the `elif`.

```
if line[-2:] == '0':
    twos += 1
elif line[-3:] == '000':
    eights +=1
```

should become:

```
line = line.strip()
if line[-1] == '0':
    twos += 1      
else:
    continue  # a micro optimization.
              # If it does not end with '0', obviously it can't end with '000'
if line[-3:] == '000':
    eights +=1
```

Comment: `line.strip()` *may* want to be `line.rstrip()`. Personally I prefer a full strip but just in case I figured I'd leave the comment for the OP.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse The chances OP will have a wanted leading space or newline are very slim, but point taken.

Answer (score -1):

as you said a binary numer is divisible by 2 when last digit is 0 therefore:

```
 line = line.strip() // The strip() method returns a copy of the string with both leading and trailing characters removed 
    if line[-1] == '0':
        twos += 1
```